# How can i define the $to variable in Mail function of Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hi I do not know where the problem is because the variable is defined but laravel says that it's not my code is:

```
$to = $request->input('mail_contacto');
$razon_social = $request->input('razon_social');
$password = str_random(15);
$data = ['password' => $password];

Mail::send('email.email', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->to($to, $razon_social)->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

It says this error:

> ErrorException in ClientesController.php line 134: Undefined variable:
>   to

But the variable is defined and it's not empty because i checked it.

What can it be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to used closure with the `use` keyword

```
Mail::send('email.email', $data, function($message) use ($to,$razon_social)
{
    $message->to($to, $razon_social)->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables `$to` and `$razon_social` are not included in the local scope of the function. Try to apply the `use` keyword to include them:

```
Mail::send('email.email', $data, function($message) use ($to, $razon_social)
{
    $message->to($to, $razon_social)->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

You can read more about the `use` keyword [here](https://blog.dubbelboer.com/2012/04/07/php-use-keyword.html).

Answer (score 0):

What version of laravel are you using ? i recommend looking into laravel mailables. here is a reference link : https://laravel-news.com/laravel-mailable-the-new-and-improved-way-to-send-email-in-laravel . when you used the "use" syntax from above answers , what was the error? was it the same ?